# Change symbol colours and shapes on EPs exported from Matlab

Tags: adobe-illustrator, eps

I have a graph exported in an EPS format from Matlab, and I wanted to change some of the symbol colours. Is there any way to do this without having to hold down the shift key when accessing the shape fill/line colour option? I guess the symbols are not vector files which is why I can’t change the colours more easily.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question fully. If you are able to edit the strokes and fills, then the images must be vectors.  If the images are raster, then Illustrator can't really do much with them.  Try to find out which you have, and add more info please.

Comment: Also you can use **Select -> Same -> Fill**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
1) From the Swatches panel, click the flyout menu and select Add Used Colors. This will create and apply a global swatch for every color Illustrator finds in the art.
2) Edit your desired color swatches as necessary. Editing a global swatch will be reflected in all object that have been assigned to that swatch.